# How to disable Firefox from adding tags in the URL bar?

Tags: firefox

Every now and then, I fat finger something while typing in the URL bar, and Firefox starts adding 'tags' such as the one below reading "Startpage—Private Search Engine" with a clickable X widget to close the tag:

[image: Firefox adds a tag to the URL bar while I am typing]

There is no circumstance where I desire this behavior in Firefox. **How can I eliminate tags from ever showing up in Firefox's URL bar?** (I am using Firefox on Ubuntu, for what it is worth.)

Bonus points if you can explain what behavior on my end creates these tags in the first place.

**EDIT:** I am using the configuration that separates search from the URL bar (i.e. I have a separate search bar on the top right, with a favicon indicating which search engine is in use).

Comment: Is it always Startpage? Are you using Startpage as your search engine?

Comment: It is not always Startpage. I am using Startpage as my search engine.

Comment: Then it's Ctrl+K that triggers it for Startpage. It's a leftover from when location bar and search bar were separate.

Comment: @gronostaj Not sure what you mean there? When I type <CTRL>-K nothing happens, whether or not the URL bar is in focus.

Comment: Oh, it's probably a different shortcut on macOS. [This](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_search) says Cmd+K or Cmd+Opt+F.

Comment: Ctrl+K triggers it (showing duckduckgo) on my ubuntu+firefox.  Even this [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys/) tried and failed to override such built-in keyboard shortcuts, so there might not be a simple way.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune Nope. <CTRL>+K is irrelevant.